# Messages skipping Gmail's inbox

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

Cleaning "*all mail*" in Gmail, I noticed there was a lot of unread messages that were not in the inbox, in the trash or in some label. They're just messages that I received and had never seen... This is not the first time I think the messages are skipping the inbox, but I don't have any filter with "*skip the inbox*" and it's not a POP account. I'm using *Priority Inbox*.

What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Where go these messages?

Two screenshots: The first my inbox with no unread messages, including the labels:

[image: inbox with no unread messages]
The second, after an *"is:unread"* search. Note that before performing the search, I cleaned the spam and the trash. I just don't know where are these unread messages, once they aren't in the trash, the spam or in any labels.

[image: after an _"is:unread"_ search]

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know, never seen this before. Would be great to get a screenshot with personal information blurred out. Make sure you click on a individual message when you take the screenshot.

Comment: @phwd, now I don't have none because I cleaned yesterday. Should I wait a new message to post a screenshot or close this question and ask later when I have the screenshot? Thanks

Comment: @phwd, I finally done the screenshots.

Comment: I have this issue too!!!

Comment: @nemke, It seems this happens with a lot of people... After searching for "messages skipping inbox" in Gmail Help Forum I discovered there're many users with the same problem. They don't use filters, POP, IMAP or anything else but their messages skip the inbox. What I do now is check "all mail" everyday...

Comment: Yes, I submitted a bug to Google. I also asked on my twitter profile and had a response from one follower. He wasn't even aware of the problem until he searched with in:unread. I think that all people should file a bug to Google so they can become aware of the problem.

Comment: Could this be connected to Gmail's [smart labels](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/03/gmail-smart-labels.html), which try to identify (and sometimes archive) bulk email?  I notice that all the unready messages are from forums...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to delete all your filters and recreate them. I had a similar problem and I think it was just a complicated filter setup. Recreating the filters helped me.

Comment: this solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that all the unread messages that you have in your account are from ProZ.com (excluding the once you have blurred) and also the latest email is dated to Sep 24 - i.e., many months ago. It's possible that you have a label/filter that is making this messages skip the inbox. You should really check out each and every filter that you have. Also, I have checked it out for my inbox and this has happened to me too. I am not sure but I think this happens when you are receiving a large number of emails from the same forum/same email address frequently and you do not read them for quite some time and "Archeive" them manually for a few times - the emails coming after that are archived automatically.